# Unexpected JSTL EL results

Tags: jsp, foreach, jstl, el

I'm having unexpected results from a  loop which displays my news posts from a MySQL database. Here is the EL code:

```
<table class="newsbox" width="400" border="0">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td class="date">Date/time</td>
<td class="username">Posted By</td>
<td class="title">Title</td>
<td class="content">Action</td>
</tr>
<c:forEach items="${nwg.getNews()}" varStatus="loop">
<tr>
<td class="date"><c:out value="${nwg.getNews().get('date')[loop.index]}"/></td>
<td class="username"><c:out value="${nwg.getNews().get('username')[loop.index]}" /></td>
<td class="title"><c:out value="${nwg.getNews().get('title')[loop.index]}" /></td>
<td class="content"><a href="Servlet/Admin/News?action=del&id=${nwg.getNews().get('id')[loop.index]}">Delete</a> / Edit</td>
</tr>
</c:forEach>
</tbody>
</table>
```

The problem is its outputting a further 4 delete / edit links no matter how many news posts there are in the database. Like say if I have 1 news post it will display that news posts delete / edit link plus a further 4 blank delete / edit links with no id= value. I think the problem lies within the forEach loop. Help much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Sorry it's ok I've fixed it. I changed the way the forEach loop works and it's now behaving properly. Cheers anyway!